# Are distro packaging questions (creation of binary and/or source packages for distributions) on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'm about to embark myself in cleaning the [debian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/debian) tag from off topic questions and in my expeditions I find questions about creating Debian packages, like these [Packaging Go 1.5 applications for Debian-like systems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32171867/792066), [Should I override debhelper usage of the init system?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34342058/792066). Are creating packages for Debian, RPM, etc. based systems on topic?

Answer (score 5):

Questions about

- Specific programming problems

and

- Software development tools

are specifically on topic at Stack Overflow.  Creating (what are essentially) installation packages for software delivery systems meets both of these requirements.

Similar questions for parallel microsoft systems could be creating an app package for the windows store or using WIX to create an MSI for desktop deployment.

You could make the same comparison for packaging your android phone app for deployment to Google Play or similar for your Swift application to the ... apple store?  They call that iTunes still?  I dunno.  Pfft, apple, amirite?

What are *not* on topic about these tasks are the policies and operations of the delivery systems themselves.  Asking about why Google Play rejected my submission would be off topic.  The actual act of deployment can be borderline, depending on how the process is handled (e.g., publishing directly from your IDE vs. "What URL do I go to in order to upload my package?)

So as long as these questions are about how to create packages and using developer tools to deploy these packages to these distribution systems, they should be good to go.