# Snappy packaging tags

Tags: discussion, tags

I've created a [snappy-package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snappy-package) tag today for Snappy-related questions. [Snappy is a relatively new packaging system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snappy_(package_manager)) that uses the [snapcraft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snapcraft) tool to produce packages. My original intention was to try retagging some obviously wrong-tagged questions (that were using [snap-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snap-framework) or [snappy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snappy) tags that are about completely different things), see the reaction on a new tag and then tag all the rest that I've seen related to this packaging system.

Now, three of my edits were approved with one rejected, that's fine, but from what I see now, most of the questions not tagged with [snappy-package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snappy-package) were tagged with [snapcraft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snapcraft) tag, which is also fine, but now we have two rarely used tags for highly correlated things.

Maybe it's better to have one tag? I've also thought about difference between the tool and the packaging system in general before creating the [snappy-package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snappy-package) tag, I think if we're to use both tags we will see both of them on about 95% of questions related to Snappy, so in my opinion it's better to have one more generic tag (until there are enough questions that will benefit from separation of these tags).

What should we do about that? Draw the line between two tags and retag related questions accordingly (then something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32940489/install-go-programming-language-on-ubuntu-core-snappy) is probably more about [snappy-package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snappy-package) than [snapcraft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snapcraft) and all [snapcraft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snapcraft)-tagged questions should also get [snappy-package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snappy-package) tag) or leave just one tag (whatever that is) and retag everything to this one tag?

---

#### update

I should've researched this topic better, on askubuntu there is a [`snap`](https://askubuntu.com/tags/snap/info) tag that has synonyms of `snapcraft` and `snap-package`. We can't use [snap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snap) as we have it already for a different purpose, but we can rename [snappy-package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snappy-package) to [snap-package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snap-package) to be consistent with askubuntu and make [snapcraft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snapcraft) be a synonym to that.

Comment: Neither tag is much on-topic for Stack Overflow IMO. Snappy is not a *programming* tool. And even "How do I install Go from a snap package" is stretching it. - Now if someone was to inquire about generating snap filesystems, their layout, or something else to compensate the scarce official documentation... perhaps. But nobody is. → So `snapcraft` (the tool) and its usage was surely better suited for Super User.

Comment: @mario: I thought we have this question solved [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320577/), Snappy is what's going to be used by some developers to package their software, same way as rpm/deb tags or even nsis.

Comment: Whatever you do, please add something to the tag-wiki and tag-excerpt. If you're going to create a tag, at least tell people what it's about.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: Sure, I just want to see which particular way of handling this is more appropriate first.

Answer (score 1):

OK, as there are no opinions on the subject, I think we should proceed with renaming [snappy-package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snappy-package) to [snap-package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snap-package) to be consistent with Askubuntu and then make [snapcraft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snapcraft) be a synonym of [snap-package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snap-package), again as was [already done on Askubuntu](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15599/).