# How should Stack Overflow improve its response to questions moderators consider self promotion?

Tags: discussion, moderation, self-promotion

First some quick background:

A few weeks ago I was working with VS Code and noticed they had created an issue template such that any Questions that would otherwise have been asked in their GitHub repo were redirected to Stack Overflow with their tag. See their new issue selection here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new/choose which links here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-code

Last week, I had just finished answering and closing a bunch of questions on my relatively popular Clean Architecture repo and I decided to follow suit, as seen here:
https://github.com/ardalis/CleanArchitecture/issues/new/choose
linking here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ardalis-cleanarchitecture

I then took one of the FAQ questions for the project (very simple how to install the template), used the above tag, and self-answered it:

> [image]

Sometime later, I got an email, saying:

> [image]

This email did *not* say that my question had been deleted nor did it suggest the need for any action on my part. I did not receive any notification at all that my question was removed. The email comes across as a friendly "FYI, take care you don't step over the line when it comes to self-promotion" which is great, except that apparently, it was misleading since actions were already taken in this case (deleting the question).

I sent an email to the moderation team asking for clarification, explaining that my use of the new tag was directly following the example set by VS Code (another open-source free tool). Days later I got an email that didn't answer my question and instead said to post something here, so I am, and I fully expect someone to moderate *this* message because it's duplicate, too specific, or whatever. (But if that's the case hey you folks had your chance when I emailed you directly.)

Note: Nowhere in the deleted question does it say why the questions were deleted nor was there any communication to me through other means (email, SO inbox, etc.) advising me of the action that was taken, why it was taken, or what I should correct (apart from the vague email referenced above, which I did a review but assumed since no other communication came in that I hadn't breached any policy since it didn't say I had or that any action had been taken).

How should Stack Overflow improve its response to questions moderators delete because they are considered too self-promotional?

Comment: Of course I did just find the link to recently deleted questions, so there's that. :)
https://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/13729

Comment: We can't access that link though, so you're better off posting a link directly to the question and screenshoting it (for non-10K users).

Comment: It's not relevant to the questions I'm asking here. It was deleted. Given that it was deleted, should I have been notified? Also, is it appropriate for me to send users of my open source package to SO to ask questions on a specific tag I follow?

Comment: Possibly relevant: [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/11682469) and [Do any companies have agreements with Stack Overflow to use the site as a support channel? What's the best course of action if not?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256088/11682469)

Comment: Regarding your first question: [Send notification when question is closed or deleted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258057/11682469) (status declined). Regarding your second question: Only the standards of Stack Overflow matter (that's also why "... explaining that my use of the new tag was directly following the example set by VS Code (another open source free tool)." is irrelevant).

Comment: @JeanneDark Thanks. Given that, what's your opinion on the VS Code link to SO for any questions? In my case, the repo in question is just a solution template for building .NET apps and most questions are code/architecture related so I would expect them to be SO appropriate. There is no 'company' or 'service' involved. It's just code on GitHub.

Comment: [1/2] It's a difference whether you as the author post a question on SO (and do not state that this is your product) or if you send people with questions about your project to SO. It also makes a difference whether there is already a community on SO for that topic or if you (as a product owner) create that tag. Noone stated that you can't send people to SO to ask question (though it might not be a good idead). The moderator just stated that it's not ok to ask questions about your own product without stating your affiliation.

Comment: [2/2] Without seeing your question, I can't say if it was a "real" question which could have been asked by any other user or mostly a promotion post.

Comment: For 10k users: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67140565/how-do-i-install-the-dotnet-template-for-ardalis-cleanarchitecture https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67110664/how-do-we-share-reuse-the-same-models-between-api-endpoints-to-keep-things-dry

Comment: @BDL If the moderator said somewhere that they deleted the question because I didn't identify myself, I haven't yet seen where they said that. That would be a great thing to include in the notification given to the question author (that apparently moderators don't want because it would increase the whining they would need to listen to, per https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258138/13729). I only just found the link to deleted questions in my profile after posting this because it was a tiny link I had to scroll to the bottom of my profile to discover.

Comment: Honestly, the biggest problem seems to be that you are linking to the project in the question as well; they aren't actually needed and that *does* make your questions/answers look like stealth advertisements. If those links weren't there, I suspect that the questions/answers would not have been deleted.

Comment: Per @BoltClock the first one is the one under discussion (thanks), about CleanArchitecture.

Comment: @yivi Perhaps (I see you just edited it) but part of my frustration is with the whole communication process (or lack thereof), which is not reflected in your update.

Comment: @yivi Agreed that's why email communication is sometimes better for this kind of thing. I didn't want to have to provide background multiple times for multiple questions that were all related to the same incident, as that would only add to the burden of the readers.

Comment: Now that I see the question: Looks like offtopic for beeing a request for a off-site resource (a nugget package).

Comment: I edited this question to include a screenshot of the original. I can see from this discussion that I should have not linked to the project referenced by the question in the question itself (though that does seem odd since it might make it harder for folks to know what's being talked about) and I should have mentioned in either/both Q and A that I'm the author of that package. Or perhaps I was just wrong to want to "seed" the tag with an FAQ question in the first place.

Comment: *"though that does seem odd since it might make it harder for folks to know what's being talked about"* That isn't what questions are for, that is for tags, and their tag wiki are for. If you want someone to understand what your product is, then ensure that it have an appropriate tag wiki (that doesn't also come across as advertising).

Comment: @gnat It helps and I will keep it in mind, thanks. If that was the thing that got the answer (and/or question) deleted, it would have been nice to point it out *in the notification to me that the content was deleted* or at least in the Deleted Question view in my profile.

Comment: @Larnu I've never done anything with tag wikis before, and wasn't aware it was a tool I should use for this kind of thing. No doubt if I were to add a tag and wiki it would, of necessity, link to the project in question. At that point is it suddenly considered "too promotional" ?

Comment: Not at all, @ssmith . Many of the tag wiki's link to the vendor's official website as that where you'll find documentation, update downloads, FAQs, etc.

Comment: @ssmith: Linking to the product website from a tag wiki should be fine, but I personally would wait until there is a real question in that tag. Atm, the two of you seem to be the only one. The tag wouldn't even exist without your questions.

Comment: I appreciate everyone's time here and I think I now have a better idea of what I did to get the original question deleted. The biggest aggravation for me was the total lack of communication about this at the time the action was taken. No email about the delete. A misleading email saying I might have been self-promoting but no specific reference to the action moderators took. No reason for the deletion given in the deleted question view itself. If any of that had been provided I wouldn't be bothering all of you here today and would have happily complied with SO policies.

Comment: per my understanding, general expectation is that you are going to apply moderator guidance in _new_ posts and referring deleted old ones from this perspective looks unnecessary. I'd say more, it is slippery from this angle: since they can't tell whether you are interested in digging out old posts or not, linking them carries a risk of negative reaction, "hey I wanted to start smarter, all new and bury old painful mistakes, why do you put salt in my wounds by pestering me with links to these"

Comment: *shockingly* this question has now been closed as duplicate. Someone thinks it's a duplicate of "What is the policy about X" when the actual question is "How to improve the response users get when mods delete their stuff because of (policy)" which are perhaps related, but I think anyone can see they're not [duplicates].

Comment: I don't think you realize that hundreds of questions a month get deleted. Three users with enough rep for that vote privilege can delete one with zero moderator involvement, after it has been closed by three votes.   Seems like you think your case is special when in reality it is a normal daily occurrence across the network. If something is missing in your activity logs in profile then perhaps that issue needs to be raised

Comment: @charlietfl I realize. And in many of those cases it may well be that the people asking those questions don't complain that they were deleted. Some might not even care. But in my case, and apparently based on other links shared here other cases as well, the experience was a very frustrating one. And I've been using SO since it was launched, so probably I should know *all the things* but I don't or I don't remember them all, every time. So, some better communication would have really helped me better understand the issue. I'm not special; others share this frustration. Can it be avoided?

Comment: @ssmith - believe it, we actually get your frustration, far from everything on SO is without flaw. It also had (I am not sure if you followed the news) a fairly recent moderator and curator exodus following the forming rift between SE and the community. Finally, the model obviously did not scale well - the number of active curators/mods is in decline, but the number of low-quality posts is rising. With little to no effort from SE. So when you take to meta with a semi-rant about the experience you had, it is mostly met with explanations of what you did wrong and not much else. Besides [1/2]

Comment: [2/2], given the huge pile of feature requests stuck in limbo *for years*, not many are willing to spend time discussing improvements that will be implemented in 10 years' time (or, more likely, never). Not that I don't think we shouldn't try, but chances are slim at best (in your case they are even worse since the request was declined before). You can still make a feature request post here on MSE about the deletion notifications - but please, make sure the post is level-headed and explains well why should dev time be allocated to it.

Comment: @charlietfl Just FYI: You're *dramatically* low in saying "hundreds of questions a month get deleted" (but correct :) ). The number of questions deleted per month is in the high tens of thousands.There are about 8.5M deleted questions on SO, which makes for an average of about 56,000 questions deleted each month since 2008-09-15. Obviously, that number has varied quite a bit over the years. A very quick look indicates the current number of questions which are deleted each month in more recent years to be between about 70,000 and 100,000 per month, depending on the month and year.

Comment: @Makyen Started with *hundreds a day* and thought I might be over reaching without any empirical data. That's quite an amazing volume. Now I know 3 digits an hour is not an over reach at times

Comment: And again, *I realize there are a lot of deleted questions*. Like, a LOT. So, a reasonable response might be "We know the experience isn't always ideal, but this is the best we can reasonably do." But if there are ideas anyone has on ways to make it a *better* experience, that's what I'd love to see here.

Comment: @Makyen: Apparently [1.4 million deleted posts in one year](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392550/2019-a-year-in-moderation#comment747019_392550) (2019)

Answer (score -9, accepted):

Note: the question in its current edited form is "How should Stack Overflow improve its response to questions moderators consider self promotion?"

Stack Overflow's current "response to questions moderators consider self promotion" is perfect and does not require improvement.

That process is to delete the question (and any associated answers). There might be an email letting a user know they might recently have posted something that appeared self-promotional, but as @Oleg noted in his answer that's unrelated to the community curation process.

Users are expected to know, understand, and remember all Stack Overflow policies that may relate to their question, in their current and most-recently updated form, before asking any question on the site.

Users are expected either to not care whether their recently posted content is available on the site or not, or if they do care, they are expected to discover the current status of their content by periodically polling the site looking for changes.

In short, if users find the current "response to questions moderators consider self promotion" to be frustrating or in need of improvement, the problem is with the user, not the process.

Comment: The snark is strong with this one...

Comment: If every suggestion to improve the process is downvoted, and the only upvoted answer is actually just a comment on the question, the status quo must as good as can be.

Comment: Your question is marked [discussion], not [feature-request], so there is no expectation of answers being proposals. Your other answers seem to be written such that all of the work is done by others, with no responsibility resting on your shoulders. Generally, that goes over as well as snark does.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I certainly have a better understanding of the issues with my original question and I'm not questioning why it was deleted. That's clear, now, after this discussion. My question (the one edited above) now, though, is could there have been a better way for me to gain this understanding than what occurred in this case? Assuming, obviously, that I didn't know before I posted what I know now. If no better way exists (or is practical), so be it. I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: @ssmith FYI, marking a self-answer as accepted won’t do anything except put a green check on it. The answers will still be sorted by score. This one will appear below Oleg’s, so future visitors will see his at the top and interpret that as the canonical answer.

Comment: @DanBron Thanks. I'm aware that's how it works. Diligent readers will also note that his answer is pretty much a comment, not an answer. Even more diligent readers will see Heretic Monkey's above comment that with a [discussion] tag there's apparently no expectation of actual answers so ¯\_(ツ)_/¯. In any case as a closed not-really-duplicate question I don't expect there to be many readers after today anyway.

Comment: @HereticMonkey regarding "your answers seem to be written such that all of the work is done by others", they're written to answer the question as stated in the title. If the only answer is to be a better user and follow the rules so your stuff isn't deleted and thus you won't miss notifications (that aren't sent) or need any explanation about why (that wasn't given except in this Q) then I must once more submit to you that this answer *is* that answer (considered snarky or not).

Comment: @DanBron - depends on how people sort it, actually, the OP is free to accept anything they want so long as they think this is the most helpful answer *to them*. It also isn't true that the most upvoted is the canonical answer - it just means that more people agree with what's presented in it than disagree, that's all. I am not happy about how this discussion went, but the Q&A started on the wrong foot, so this is an expected course, frankly.

Answer (score 15):

Firstly, the email you got and the community curation process are not tightly coupled. There is no "email first, curate later" policy. Also, regardless of the popularity of the project/tool/product, you are (as we all are) expected to acquaint yourself with the community guidelines on when it is fine to use SO as a support channel.

---

Secondly, it is considered common courtesy (actually, this is an understatement: it is more of a requirement) to avoid artificially creating tags for projects (open-source or not) or products. Citing [the FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253852/11407695):

> There have to be some existing questions about your product on the site

If no one unaffiliated asks questions about your project on SO, chances are it is premature to consider SO your support channel. If you [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ardalis%20clean&searchOn=3) for questions about the project (and not the [Clean Architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/clean-architecture/info) itself), you will find only 4 of them (at the time of this writing) with [only 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57785213/clean-architecture-for-asp-net-mvc-which-layer-i-write-the-viewmodels) directly related.

---

Finally, a small comment on the following:

> so I am, and I fully expect someone to moderate this message because it's duplicate, too specific, or whatever.

Note that by posting on Meta, you are asking the community to weigh in, not only the moderators. Adding slightly veiled confrontational language usually results in posts *not* being well-met. If the question already has answers elsewhere, it will be rightfully closed against the duplicate target.

---

The following question was present in the original revision and came up several times in comments:

> Should users be notified via email and/or in their profile somehow when one of their questions is deleted?

I would say they should (as an opt-in preference probably, plus there is a huge pile of potential issues to discuss), but the feature was declined before (see [Jeanne Dark](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/11682469/jeanne-dark)'s [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406956/how-should-stack-overflow-improve-its-response-to-questions-moderators-consider#comment838177_406956)) or left unnoticed when it resurfaced (see [this MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340714/deletion-notification) or [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358382/notification-when-a-followed-post-is-deleted)).

Comment: Thanks, Oleg. Good info. To be fair this is all a comment on my question, not an answer to it.

Comment: @ssmith - comments are severely character limited and have limited formatting options, so any extensive response to questions can only live in an answer properly, unfortunately. Anyways, it wasn't my intention to address the "improvement of response" part - wanted to respond to some of the points you made in the question itself.

Comment: Also thanks for the link to the question that is directly related - I'd actually not seen it before now (which is part of why I'd like a tag I can follow so I can help folks more quickly). Cheers.

Comment: Oleg - I know, your "answer" works well to present the detailed comments you had. I kind of wish there were a way to say that an "answer" is really a "long comment" but there's only so much one can do. My only real concern is that your "answer" will get more upvotes than any actual proposed solution to the question/problem at hand (as is so far apparent).

Comment: @ssmith - that really doesn't matter which one gets how many votes - you are requesting from the community something, that, frankly, is outside our control right now (literally). People here explained why the Q&A pair was deleted, linked you to the relevant FAQ items, provided responses to your concerns throughout the question. There is a separate process of asking for change: [meta-tag:feature-request] but as you already know, this particular one was declined before

Comment: yes this has been a helpful thread. My question isn't (and certainly wasn't before others edited it multiple times) "can you add this feature" but instead is "how might we improve this user experience". Such improvement might come from new features, or it could come from any number of other ideas. So far nobody but me has proposed any solutions, though, sadly.

Comment: @ssmith [reposting due to link issues] FYI, about the deleted question: see [Makoto](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/354714/11407695)'s in the Q&A on questions about package managers, those are not usually very welcome on the site. Overall, I think you can still do what you originally intended, but use the question that is directly related to your project (the only one found mentioned in the answer) and start from there. The questions will naturally come in once users start using the new issue template

Comment: Giving that a shot... https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ardalis-cleanarchitecture/info

Comment: @ssmith - I mopped up both the question and the answer a little. You can actually include the links, no one will blame you for that (certainly no need to remark on that, I removed it), there is a proper disclaimer. Without them, the answer just lacks additional usefulness it could get. The original answer did not contain any reference to the affiliation and that's what lead to the deletion (apart from the question not following the guidelines). Usually, if the post just contains *mine* or *I created* this is enough to avoid all issues with self-promotion.

Comment: I did fill in info and guidelines - are you not seeing them?

Comment: @ssmith - ah, they are in the suggested edits review queue, sorry I missed the "pending edit" part. You should probably elaborate on the project in the wiki itself, but I think it will do for now (approved both - the wiki could be improved further, but that can be addressed in the natural course of things, need another reviewer to weigh in).

Answer (score -9):

Stack Overflow should provide users with a log of how their content has been modified by moderators somewhere in their profile, and potentially in their SO inbox.

The moderation team has come out against sending actual notifications to users whose content is deleted (see [Send notification when question is closed or deleted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258057/send-notification-when-question-is-closed-or-deleted/258138#258138)), but this approach would not involve any outgoing notification. Instead, if users somehow uncover the fact that moderators have deleted their content, they can at least go to a single place in the web site to learn exactly what was done and why.

Naturally any actions presented to the user in this way should also include the rationale for the actions that were taken, and any links to policies, etc. used to justify the action.

Comment: Why are you posting multiple answers? Simply post one and answer the question there.

Comment: Because there are multiple possible solutions to this problem, and Stack Overflow has a voting mechanism people can use to vote up or down the solutions they think are best.

Answer (score -11):

Stack Overflow should notify authors of content when it is deleted by moderators. It should include the reason for the deletion with a link to the policy that was violated, if possible. If the emails are unwanted by the user, they should be able to adjust their notification settings.

The fact that this approach has been [suggested and rejected in the past notwithstanding](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258057/send-notification-when-question-is-closed-or-deleted/258138#258138), it would have provided a better experience for the question author (me) in this example.